# Making my SSIS package portable - how to do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I know how to create SSIS packages and getting my data source and destinations.
But what will I have to do in my package if I want to make it portable in the sense where I can change the source and destination connection strings when I move my package onto another PC?

Answer (score 4):

Couple of options. Do you mean you want to make the solution portable, so that you can develop on different PC's, or do you mean you want to make the end-deployable package portable?

You can use package configurations for both. They're accessible under the SSIS / Configurations menu. You specify the properties of objects you want to make dynamic, and this gets saved to an XML file (e.g. connection strings, path locations, variable values).

You can change this xml file in a text editor, and when the package runs, it'll use those values. However, if you're developing on multiple machines, this is still a little niggly. You  might need to re-specify which configuration file to use when opening the solution on a new PC.

Instead, if it's DB connection strings, look at using trusted connections. They mean you don't have to enter SQL credentials. If it's for file locations, this won't work, but you could replicate directory structures or something to get around that.

If it's for deployment, then package configurations are definitely the way to go. Make sure your project is using configuration files, then when you compile you can choose to create a "deployment package". I think this is under Build options. This creates an installer file packaged with the config file, and when you run this installer you can view / change configuration values.

Edit - found a bit of a more detailed response here : http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_2005_making_ssis_packages_portable.htm

Answer (score 1):

Along with package configurations. You can create a deployment utility, which you can then use to do a file system deployment. When you run the deployed executable you will be able to select which configuration file to run the package with.

This setting is set to 'false' by default

Project > Properties... > Deployment Utility > CreateDeploymentUtility = true